# The hosted network couldn't be started

Tags: cmd

i use HUAWEI USB internet connection (3G, HSPA+)

i tried to set a new virtual Hosted network but it was useless.

I made a batch file to insert orders (programming CMD) to make a virtual hosted network, it worked for only two days, then when i tried to start the virtual hosted network ("netsh wlan start hostednetwork") it giving me an error :

```
 The hosted network couldn't be started. A device attached to the system is not functioning.
```

Comment: Is the device enabled in `Device Manager` ?

Comment: i dont know, but when i open device manager there is no undefined devices i.e no problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error as well. But restarting my computer fixed it. Its probably a stupid thing to ask but it works sometimes.

Comment: I don't think this actually solves the problem, but is a workaround that causes you to no longer run into the problem. While it is a resolution, it does not address the users question which is fundamentally "what is going wrong, and what can i do to fix it?"